# NotificationExtenderService not firing handleNotificationReceived

Tags: java, notifications, ionic2, onesignal, silent

I am extending `NotificationExtenderService` inside a Java class as per OneSignal documentation here [One signal doc](https://documentation.onesignal.com/v3.0/docs/android-customizations), but I realized that returning true prevents the notification from showing. Perfect so far, the problem is I still need to trigger the `handleNotificationReceived` inside my typescript code.

Here below the Java code extending :

```
public class NotificationExtenderBareBonesExample extends NotificationExtenderService {
@Override
protected boolean onNotificationProcessing(OSNotificationReceivedResult receivedResult) {
    receivedResult.payload.lockScreenVisibility = Integer.parseInt("-1");
    JSONObject data = receivedResult.payload.additionalData;
    OverrideSettings overrideSettings = new OverrideSettings();
    overrideSettings.extender = new NotificationCompat.Extender() {
        @Override
        public NotificationCompat.Builder extend(NotificationCompat.Builder builder) {
            // Sets the background notification color to Green on Android 5.0+ devices.
            builder = builder.setVisibility(Integer.parseInt("-1"));
            builder = builder.setVibrate(new long[]{0L});
            return builder.setColor(new BigInteger("800d2f66", 16).intValue());
        }
    };
    OSNotificationDisplayedResult displayedResult = displayNotification(overrideSettings);
    Log.d("OneSignalExample", "Notification displayed with id: " + displayedResult.androidNotificationId);
    return true;
}
```

}

The issue I am having is that I need to call `displayNotification` for having my `NotificationReceivedHandler` triggered (it analyses the additionalData and run portions accordingly).

Ionic 2 code:

```
this.oneSignal.handleNotificationReceived().subscribe((result) => {
  alert('received ' + JSON.stringify(result));
  thisRef.writeDebug('notification received');
  let data = result.payload.additionalData;
  let chatmessage = "";
  if (data != null) {
      if(typeof data !== 'undefined' && data.length != 0)
      {
        if(typeof data.chatmessage !== 'undefined')
          console.log('chatmessage ok');
        if(typeof data.id !== 'undefined')
          thisRef._callbackOnChatMessage({chatmessage: data.chatmessage, id: data.id.toString()})
        if(typeof data.shortgeolocation !== 'undefined')
        {
          this._callbackRequestShortLocation(data.shortgeolocation);
        }
      }
      if(typeof data.othertyping !== 'undefined' && typeof thisRef._callbackOnOtherTyping !== 'undefined')
      {
        thisRef._callbackOnOtherTyping(data.othertyping);
      }
  }
});
```

Here is a preview of my notification once it arrives into my Ionic handler:

[image]

Is there any way to change the `displayType` and `Shown` value to be respectively 0 and false from the `NotificationExtenderService` so that my NotificationReceivedHandler in Ionic is called and the alert not shown? (I got this behaviour working under iOS, struggling to do the same in Android).

SOLVED, partially, I had to downgrade onesignal library to 3.5.6
in platforms/android.properties, using cordova.system.library.[keep your number x]=com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.5.6
fixes the issue. 
For ionic, the file is under platforms/android/
[image: project.properties in Android platform]

See [this](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Cordova-SDK/issues/220#issuecomment-332254428) post absolutely related.

Comment: Can you show where did you put native java class in ionic project?

Comment: For the Android portion it is under platform->android->src->com.  From there you should see a folder with your project name and a sub folder for your project id.  In short exactly where your MainActivity.java is located.  Don't forget to add the service portion inside the AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a mail from OneSignal stating that version 3.6.2 was fixing this issue.
So Android property should be **com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.6.2** now.
See my updated question for updating the file.